# Simplify the expression

Tags: php

I am writing a bunch of conditions, using if statements, is there a way to simplify this to make it look nicer?

```
$value = "1";

      if (($subvalue == 1) && ($subbucket == 1)){
        $value = "1";
      }

      if (($subvalue == 1) && ($subbucket == 2){
        $value = "1A";
      }

      if (($subvalue == 1) && ($subbucket == 3)){
        $value = "2A";
      }

      if (($subvalue == 2) && ($subbucket == 1)){
        $value = "3A";
      }

      if (($subvalue == 2) && ($subbucket == 2)){
        $value = "3B";
      }

      if (($subvalue == 2) && ($subbucket == 3)){
        $value = "3C";
      }
```

I find it's messy, is there a way to rewrite this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Stay away from `== 1` unless you want anything 'truthy' to result in a response. Use `=== 1` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General solution, if you can have any keys whatsoever:

```
$lookup = array(
  1 => array(
    1 => "1",
    2 => "1A",
    3 => "2A"),
  2 => array(
    1 => "3A",
    2 => "3B",
    3 => "3C"));

$value = $lookup[$subvalue][$subbucket];
if (!$value) $value = "1";
```

Otherwise, for successive integral keys such as shown in the question,

```
$lookup = array(
  array("1", "1A", "2A"),
  array("3A", "3B", "3C"));
$value = $lookup[$subvalue - 1][$subbucket - 1];
if (!$value) $value = "1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider this a simplified?

```
$arr = array('1', '1A', '2A', '3A', '3B', '3C');
$value = $arr[($subvalue - 1) * 3 + ($subbucket - 1)];
if (!$value) $value = "1";   // steal this line from @Amadan
```

Another solution, similarly to @Amadan's solution would be

```
$arr = array( 1 => array(1 => '1', 2 => '1A', 3 => '2A'),
              2 => array(1 => '3A', 2 => '3B', 3=> '3C'));
$value = $arr[$subvalue][$subbucket];
if (!$value) $value = "1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, something like:

```
$value = '1'; $res = array('1', '1A', '2A', '3A', '3B', '3C');
for($i=0,$n=1,$q=1; $i<6; $i++,$q++){
  if($i === 3){
    $n = 2; $q = 1;
  }
  if($subvalue === $n && $subbucket === $q){
    $value = $res[$i];
  }
}
```